# Friend all classes that inherit from a class

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

This is more of an intellectual curiosity than an actual problem. I was wondering if there is a way, in C++, to do the following: let `A` be a class. I want to make a class `B` friend with all the classes that inherit from `A`.

Before you say it: I obviously know that friendship is not inherited. What I would like to do is to make a `template friend` statement, maybe using SFINAE, to friend `B` with each and every class `C` so that `C` inherits from `A`.

Is such a thing even possible? I tried to start from the simplest case: can you make a class friend with all other classes? Obviously I know this doesn't make any sense, one could just make things public, but maybe from this starting point things can be perfected to select only those classes that inherit from `A`.

Comment: You can provide wrappers in `A` (possibly `protected`) that access `private` members of `B`. Classes derived from `A` could then call those wrappers on their base. I'm pretty sure that's as close as you can get to your goal.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense! However, say that I am writing a library, that both `A` and `B` are classes of my library, but that an user should be able to freely inherit from `A` and have `B` as a friend...

Comment: (I know this is not something you should actually do, I already found another more lengthy, more reasonable solution, but I still have the curiosity of whether or not this is even possible)

Comment: If a user-defined class `X` (whether derived from `A` or otherwise) wants to have `B` as a friend, all its author needs to do is to add `friend class B;` to the definition of `X`. Not sure what good this is supposed to do though: since `B` has no idea of the existence of `X`, it wouldn't normally attempt to access members of `X`, private or otherwise; unless some kind of template trickery is going on.

Comment: With a bit of template machinery, inheritance from above idiom and protected visibility, [you can get it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fWaAdYyPnvC8fBU8) somehow. Would it work for you? I'm not sure it's worth putting it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A work-around would be to use an inherited "key" access.

```
// Class to give access to some A members
class KeyA
{
private:
    friend class B; // Give access to base class to create the key
    KeyA() = default;
};


class A
{
public: // public, but requires a key to be able to call the method
    static void Foo(KeyA /*, Args... */) {}
    static void Bar(KeyA /*, Args... */) {}
};


class B
{
protected:
    static KeyA GetKey() { return KeyA{}; } // Provide the key to its whole inheritance
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    void Foo() { A::Foo(GetKey()); } // Use A member with the key.
};
```